# Make an option in input field inactive if it already exists in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the page I am building I have an option to make an appointment. This option is an input field with the 'available' hours for appointment as options in it.

The code looks like this :

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Hour:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <select class="form-control" id="time">
            <option value="Time" class="">Time</option>
                        <option value="10am" class="">10:00-10:30</option>
                        <option value="1030am" class="">10:30-11:00</option>
                        <option value="11am" class="">11:00-11:30</option>
                        <option value="1130am" class="">11:30-12:00</option>
                        <option value="12pm" class="">12:00-12:30</option>
                        <option value="1230pm" class="">12:30-13:00</option>
                        <option value="1pm" class="">13:00-13:30</option>
                        <option value="130pm" class="">13:30-14:00</option>
                        <option value="2pm" class="">14:00-14:30</option>
                        <option value="230pm" class="">14:30-15:00</option>
                        <option value="3pm" class="">15:00-15:30</option>
                        <option value="330pm" class="">15:30-16:00</option>
                        <option value="4pm" class="">16:00-16:30</option>
                        <option value="430pm" class="">16:30-17:00</option>
                        </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I also have an ajax request which returns an array with the already booked hours.

What I want to do(but have no idea how) is : to make all the booked hours inactive options in the list I have.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: _"I also have an ajax request which returns an array with the already booked hours."_ Can you show the array please?

Comment: ["10am", "11am", "4pm"]

Comment: Ever think of populating this Selection list by way of JQuery?  That way it is populated on the result of the ajax call?

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over each `<option>` and set it to disabled if its value is present in the array you mention. Otherwise re-set it to enabled.

```js
const youArray = ["10am", "11am", "4pm"];

$('#time option').toArray().map($).forEach(function(optionEl) {
  if (youArray.indexOf(optionEl.val()) >= 0) {
    optionEl.prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    optionEl.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Hour:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="time">
      <option value="Time" class="">Time</option>
      <option value="10am" class="">10:00-10:30</option>
      <option value="1030am" class="">10:30-11:00</option>
      <option value="11am" class="">11:00-11:30</option>
      <option value="1130am" class="">11:30-12:00</option>
      <option value="12pm" class="">12:00-12:30</option>
      <option value="1230pm" class="">12:30-13:00</option>
      <option value="1pm" class="">13:00-13:30</option>
      <option value="130pm" class="">13:30-14:00</option>
      <option value="2pm" class="">14:00-14:30</option>
      <option value="230pm" class="">14:30-15:00</option>
      <option value="3pm" class="">15:00-15:30</option>
      <option value="330pm" class="">15:30-16:00</option>
      <option value="4pm" class="">16:00-16:30</option>
      <option value="430pm" class="">16:30-17:00</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just filter by the values in the array:

```
var optionsSet = ["10am", "11am", "4pm"];
$('#time').find('option').filter(function() {
 return optionsSet.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0;
}).prop('disabled',true);
```

Just note that previously disabled will need to be enabled if they change...

This enables then disables only the current ones in the array:

```
$('#time').find('option').prop('disabled',false).filter(function() {
 return optionsSet.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0;
}).prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Damn you beat me to `.filter()` :) How could I forget!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a selector for your booked hours options. and use that to disable the items.

```
// contains the list of booked hours
resp = ['Time','10am', '330pm'];

function update(){
  var sel = '';

  for(var i=0; i < resp.length; i++){
    sel += ",#time [value='" + resp[i] + "'] ";
  }
  sel = sel.substr(1);
  $("#time option").removeAttr('disabled');
  $(sel).attr('disabled',true);
}

update();
```

Find the working code here: https://jsbin.com/geyiyubogi